# unresolved token "extern "C" void __cdecl func

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ 
I sometimes get this sort of error. However I am not able to find out whats the reason.

> RoofSettings.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0038C8) "extern
>   "C" void __cdecl func(wchar_t const *,wchar_t const *)"
>   (?func@@$$J0YAXPEB_W0@Z) referenced in function "private: static void
>   __clrcall Architecture::Helper::Settings::SetOffset(double)" (?SetOffset@Settings@Helper@Architecture@$$FCMXN@Z)

This time I am getting this error when I try this code

```
pin_ptr<const wchar_t> val = PtrToStringChars(dValue.ToString());
WCharCP offsetValue = val;
func(wcXPath, offsetValue);
```

Also the function is mentioned in .fdf file as

```
nativeCode Public void func (
     WCharCP pPropertyXPath,
     WCharCP pPropertyValue );
```

I have read answers of some of related questions but could not find any 
appropriate answer. Any guidance will be highly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Thank you @YSC. I have already mentioned that i have read some similar questions. but couldn't get much help

Comment: If the suggested duplicate does not answer your question, you should explain why in your question unless you want it to be closed.

Comment: The linker can't find the implementation of `func`. So where is it?